# vb.net how to change values in embedded "My.Resource" files

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, my.resources

First thing I want to do:

I would like to know if an embedded resource file can be changed? If I had a test.htm in the resource area and in side that file i had the word "YourVariable", When i load form1 (Run program) it would change "YourVariable" that is in resource test.htm "my.resource.test" to "Hello World". I be using vb code to do this.

Last thing I want to do:

I know how to copy my.resource file to local hard drive and change the "YourVariable", but I can't copy it back in to my program my.resource file, with the updates.

In the first thing to do can this be done, edit resource file(s) in your program?

Comment: AFAIK, My.Resources is readonly. why not use My.Settings?

Comment: because it is a htm file in side my Resources

Comment: if that's the case, why not use a fixed file (build action = none or content) which will be copied over your application folder (by setting copy to output directory to "Copy If Newer")? and by this you could have full control of this file.